# How to get the lowest cpu consumption when having an infinite loop in a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

1.I have some infinite loops how can I get the lowest cpu consumption? Should I use a delay?

2.If I have multiple threads running in my application and one of them is THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE does it affect other threads?

My code is as this for every thread

```
procedure TMatchLanLon.Execute;
begin
 while not Terminated do
  begin
          //some code
          Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Add your Delphi version, please. It's important for thread related questions.

Comment: @TLama my delphi version is XE2

Comment: Duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715378/infinite-loops-in-separate-threads "infinite loops in separate threads")?

Comment: This question is better than the last one because the last one was focused around "low priority".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically a thread should sleep until signalled, but **not** using `Sleep` or `SleepEx`.

You create an Event and Wait for it to be signalled,either using [TEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent.Create) or direct to Win32 API with [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`Sleep` causes so many problems, including what I call "Sleeping beauty" disease. THe whole rest of your application has terminated and shut down a few hundred [microseconds](http://knockycode.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/grace-hoppers-explanation-of-a-nanosecond-and-a-microsecond/) ago, and your thread has slept for a "million years" in relative computer timing terms, and when it wakes up the rest of your application has long since terminated.  The next thing your background thread is likely to do is access some object which it has a reference to, which was frozen, and then (if you're lucky) it will crash. Don't use `Sleep` in threads. Wait for events, or use some pre-built worker thread (like the OmniThreadLibrary one).

Comment: If your thread is executing code (other than sleep), it may still do so after the application is terminated. A simple loop or a complex operation may also take seconds during which there is no interaction with the rest of the application. So sleep is not bad in that sense. If your thread crashes after a sleep, it may also crash after (or during) another operation. No saying that using sleep in a thread is good, but the reason you describe isn't either.

Comment: Windows stops all threads on application exit before deallocating any resources.  Sleep() is just fine in threads - I've been using it, (for its proper purposes, not as a polling crutch in a comms-challenged application), for decades.

Comment: 'If your thread is executing code (other than sleep), it may still do so after the application is terminated' - no, it cannot.  All threads either have their state set so that they are never run again or, if running on a different core than the one that exited, have their processor interrupted to stop them.  When all threads have stopped, resources are deallocated.

Comment: There is one scenarion I can think of where sleep() might cause a problem on shutdown - if a sleeping thread wakes up and attempts a direct write to a form, (or component thereon), that has already been freed, then an AV is possible, (then again, the app is closing anyway, so just dump the exception:).  Not doing such nasty things as writing to forms helps a lot!

Comment: @GolezTrol - +1 for your logic.  No thread can run on after an app has terminated. Sleeping, running, waiting - the threads are all stopped before releasing memory, handles etc.  I can't fault your logic though - 'if sleep() is a problem then other threads that are running should be a problem too'.

Comment: True, the application (process) is actually still running, but I think Warren refers to the application object that isn't. The loop in Application.Run may have terminated, and Application.Terminated (which is just a boolean variable) may have been set to true. This is an indication that the application is to close, and thread should check for this value frequently to stop what they're doing. If you don't do so, the application won't actually close until the thread is done.

Comment: 'If you don't do so, the application won't actually close until the thread is done' - ??   Empirically, I don't need to check anything in a thread, frequently or not. If I start 100 threads with long sleep() loops and close the main form, the app just closes immediately as the main form exits and the OS kills all the threads.

Comment: It's the rogue cases where the application keeps doing stuff (bad stuff maybe) that one should really be worried about.  Access violations are not the worst case.  Think creatively and you'll begin to see how important sanity in thread programming is.

Comment: @WarrenP - well, maybe. Onviously, if there is a possibility that the app may enter some unstable state that could do harm upon sleep wakeup, then sure, explicitly shut down the thread by replacing the sleep with an event wait.  In 99% of all household threads, this is not necessary.

Comment: If the thread simply exits, yes but many threads have some finalization (even just notifying someone of them shutting down for instance, can lead to a series of UI notifications to a UI form that is already gone).

Comment: 'lead to a series of UI notifications to a UI form that is already gone' - yeah, it's best to not do things like that.  If the app is shutting down, don't process/perform any messages from threads.  If it's at all possible, it's best to just ignore the threads until the OS guts them.  If no attempts are made to explicitly terminate threads, attempts to explicitly terminate threads cannot go wrong.

Answer (score 6):

> I have some infinte loops how can i get the lowest cpu consumption ?

By blocking the loop until there is something to do.

> If I have multiple threads running in my application and one of them is THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE does it affect other threads ?

..depends .  Probably not, but if any other threads are waiting on output from this thread, or the release of a lock from it, then the other threads are effectively 'dragged down' to `THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE` as well.
Apart from this priority-inversion, (which can cause deadlocks when threads have several priority levels), spinlocks, a synchronization construct that is normally only bad, can become disastrous.